# Quickest way to get first and last item in ActiveRecord date range query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get the first and last items in a date range with ActiveRecord. I could

`BalanceLedger.where(created_at: Time.now-7.days..Time.now).order(:created_at).first`

and

`BalanceLedger.where(created_at: Time.now-7.days..Time.now).order(:created_at).last`

to get the first and last in this weekly range but this seems like it will just return a lot with each query when I am just looking for 2 entries.

What is most efficient to get the first and last in this range?

Comment: The queries, as written, will each return a single record (`.order(:created_at).first` will result in a query like `... ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1`, and likewise for `.last`), so I'm not sure what you mean by "it will just return a lot with each query."

Comment: @Jordan I am on Rails 3.2 if it matters. I thought the query would return large arrays of ActiveRecord objects and then I was just plucking first and last out.

Comment: No, `Model.where(...).order(...)` gives you a relation but doesn't touch the database, calling `first` or `last` on a relation adjusts the query to include a LIMIT clause (and reverses the order in the `last` case) and then sends the single-row query to the database.

Comment: Ok. So how I have it is best I suppose to get the first and last.

Comment: You could improve it by assigning `BalanceLedger.where(...).order(...)` to a variable and then calling `.first` and `.last` on the variable. This will save a little bit of CPU time, since you're only instantiating an ActiveRecord::Relation object once instead of twice (or, strictly speaking, twice instead of four times). (Ironically, this is exactly what Arslan's answer below does, even though they're incorrect about the number of queries that will result.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You don't have to run two queries. You can run one query, and then call `first` and `last` on it.</strike>

You can improve the code in the following way, but the two queries will be run anyway. Thanks to [@muistooshort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) and [@jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) for pointing this thing out in comments.

```
balance_ledgers = BalanceLedger.where(created_at: Time.now-7.days..Time.now).order(:created_at)
first_one = balance_ledgers.first
last_one  = balance_ledgers.last
```

**Edit:**

<strike>It actually runs one query, and I checked it in Rails console. See below:</strike>

```
>> users = User.where(created_at: Time.now-7.days..Time.now).order(:created_at)
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2) ORDER BY "users"."created_at" ASC  [["created_at", 2016-11-11 09:59:00 UTC], ["created_at", 2016-11-18 09:59:00 UTC]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 6, email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: "arslan_ali505", phone_number: nil, address: nil, created_at: "2016-11-14 16:02:27", updated_at: "2016-11-14 16:02:27", role_id: 7, temp_password: "P8ijrXZErI0=", temp_password_changed: false>, #<User id: 7, email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: "arslan_ali_arslan_ali170", phone_number: nil, address: nil, created_at: "2016-11-16 11:41:57", updated_at: "2016-11-16 18:58:37", role_id: 3, temp_password: "e27aad7b817354f3", temp_password_changed: true>, #<User id: 8, email: nil, first_name: "John", last_name: "Don", username: "jhondon213", phone_number: nil, address: nil, created_at: "2016-11-17 13:09:07", updated_at: "2016-11-17 13:09:43", role_id: 7, temp_password: nil, temp_password_changed: true>]>
>> users.first
=> #<User id: 6, email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, username: "arslan_ali505", phone_number: nil, address: nil, created_at: "2016-11-14 16:02:27", updated_at: "2016-11-14 16:02:27", role_id: 7, temp_password: "P8ijrXZErI0=", temp_password_changed: false>
>> users.last
=> #<User id: 8, email: nil, first_name: "John", last_name: "Don", username: "jhondon213", phone_number: nil, address: nil, created_at: "2016-11-17 13:09:07", updated_at: "2016-11-17 13:09:43", role_id: 7, temp_password: nil, temp_password_changed: true>
```

Comment: You might want to watch your database activity when you do this. Then reconsider your "don't have to run two queries" comment.

Comment: This code will also run two queries. The first line returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object; it does not execute a query. The next two lines will execute queries like `... ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1` and `... ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`, respectively ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html)). That's a *good* thing, because if it actually just ran one query, it would fetch *all* of the records in the given range, which might be 10,000 or 100,000 or...

Comment: This is most efficient. See comments

Comment: @Jordan It actually runs the query for only one time. And it actually fetches all the records no matter how many they are. So for records more than 100,000, one should use indexing, or query optimization.

Comment: @ArslanAli IIRC the Rails console behaves differently from a Rails app in the browser, to ease debugging. Try the latter and look at the logs.

Comment: When you `users = User.where...` in the console the console will end up calling `users.inspect` to show you the `=>...` part and that will run the query. If you want to replicate what will happen in the app, say `users = User.where... ; nil` (the `;nil` suppresses the implicit `inspect` call).

Comment: @muistooshort I get it. I have updated my answer. And much thanks for pointing this out. I learned something.

Answer (score -2):

You can try sql query also & can use it directly apart from using rails query , it will improve the execution time also.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")
```